# unable to read params

Tags: go, axios

I send a request via axios as a post because I need to send a body and params. However when it reaches my backend the params are not there!

```
async getAll(page: number, pageSize: number, filter: IFilter): Promise<Course[]> {
    const res = await request.post<{ data: Course[]; metadata: 'none' }>("/v1/courses", {
        params: {
            page: page,
            pageSize: pageSize,
        },
        data: filter,
    });

    return res.data.data;
}
```

Network tab in the browser console

```
{params: {page: 1, pageSize: 6},…}
data: 
{all: true, beginner: false, intermediate: false, advanced: false, amqp: false, databases: false,…}
params: 
{page: 1, pageSize: 6}
```

snippet

```
func (app *Courses) CoursesAllHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    clog := log.GetLoggerFromContext(ctx)

    p := r.URL.Query().Get("page")
    ps := r.URL.Query().Get("pageSize")

    var filter Filter
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&filter)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to parse request body", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
```

To me the axios call looks correct and the params method to get them in the backend as well. However when I look at the Network tab and see `data:` and `params` I wounder if I need to go deeper. So I tried:

```
p := r.URL.Query().Get("data") <--- empty


type Filter struct {
    All          bool `json:"all"`
    Beginner     bool `json:"beginner"`
    Advanced     bool `json:"advanced"`
    Intermediate bool `json:"intermediate"`
    Go           bool `json:"go"`
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

---- update ---

request dump

```
request, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
if err != nil {
    return
}

clog.Info(string(request))
```

---

```
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\r\n\r\n{\"params\":{\"page\":1,\"pageSize\":6},\"data\":{\"all\":true,\"beginner\":false,\"intermediate\":false,\"advanced\":false,\"amqp\":false,\"databases\":false,\"docker\":false,\"gcp\":false,\"go\":false,\"grpc\":false,\"java\":false,\"mux\":false,\"serverless\":false,\"vue\":false,\"spring\":false}}"}
```

Comment: Do [`httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil@go1.20.5#DumpRequest) and print the output to stdout (but convert it first to string or else you'll see an array of uint8s). Then look at the output to see if the data is there and if it is then where exactly. Also keep an eye out on the `Content-Type` header, perhaps what you're sending is not JSON, if that's the case then doing `json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&filter)` will fail.

Comment: Also you should be more specific about the problem, what do you mean when you say _"the params are not there"_? You mean that `filter` is empty? (maybe you forgot to export its fields). Or do you mean `json.Decoder.Decode` returns `EOF`? Maybe the body has already been read by some middleware. And so on... I could keep guessing but it would be more practical if you're more precise with the problem description.

Comment: @mkopriva I will try it out, thanks. When I say they are not there I mean everything in the filter is defaulted to false and page / pageSize are empty.

Comment: Then include the definition of the `Filter` struct.

Comment: @mkopriva thank for the hunt. The dump shows json and everything I excepted is there. Page, PageSize and filter. But are empty when I try to get them. Added the filter and request dump

Comment: The problem is that you are unmarshaling directly into `filter` but the JSON contains the filter data under the `"data": {...}` attribute. When you are unmarshaling JSON the structures of both the target struct and the source JSON should match (at least partially, i.e. not every JSON attribute needs to be present in the struct, but those attributes that are present MUST be at the same level of the object's hierarchy). Try `json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&struct{Data *Filter}{Data:&filter})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you looking at `r.URL.Query()` to get POST params?  You need to do something like:

```
type Request struct {
    Params struct {
        Page int `json:"page"`
        PageSize int `json:"pageSize"`
    } `json:"params"`
    Data Filter `json:"data"`
}

var req Request

err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&req)
```